# Wordpress & jQuery: Hide parent div if span is zero

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to do this on a wordpress website. I have searched and tried a few suggestions already posted but none have worked.

I want to hide the span if it contains zero when the page loads.

I have used the following code (placed in the head) but it won't hide the span.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
var propertydata = $('span.property-data');
if (propertydata.text().trim() === '0') {
  propertydata.closest('span.propertydata').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to hide:

```
<div id="dbst-show12" class="column rows other">
    Year Built : 
    <span class="property-data">0</span>
</div>
```

Ultimately I would love to hide the parent "column" if possible but would settle if I could just get the zeros to disappear.

Comment: You need to pass the jQuery object: `(function ($) {...})(jQuery);` That way, `$` inside the function refers to the passed `jQuery`. And you're missing the dash in `span.property-data` when you're hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery selector to select all 0's inside a span like this:

```
var selecton = $("span:contains(0)");
```

Then you can hide all the elements with the jQuery .hide() method:

```
selection.hide();
```

You also need to make sure that function is included inside a $(document).ready so the browser knows once the page is loaded it can run your function.

This would be the whole snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var selection = $("span:contains(0)");
selection.hide();
});
```

Here's a link to a JSFiddle with your given code: https://jsfiddle.net/kgill/uzpqdsoj/1/

You could similarly hide the whole column by selecting the div with a jQuery selector and hiding it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that doing:

```
var propertydata = $('span.property-data');
```

proertydata is getting all the values from all the spans texts so it will never be equal to 0.

You may want to do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    jQuery.each( $('span.property-data'), function( i, val ) {
        if ($(val).text().trim() === '0') {
            $(val).hide(); //hides only the span
            $(val).parent().hide(); //if you want to hide parent div also
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here's a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bv7u4hxb/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think this will work but I keep getting the error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Sorry if the previous was a dumb question, I'm not very proficient with javascript.

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK!!!!! I moved the script from the head to the footer (below the body tag) and it worked!!! Thanks so much for the help!!!!